# How to sum up objects property values by date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to iterate over an array of objects and add similar properties by date and return a new array with the summed up data. Here is an example:

The data below is for each day of the week, I would like to get the sum of TV, Video, and DVD for the month. Each block of code will have a date stamped.

```
    var i = [
   {
      "0":{
         "TV":"200",
         "Video":"50",
         "DVD":"150",
         "Date":"Fri Jul 18 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500"
      }
   },
   {
      "1":{
         "TV":"150",
         "Video":"60",
         "DVD":"150",
         "Date":"Fri Jul 25 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500"
      }
   },
   {
      "2":{
         "TV":"350",
         "Video":"20",
         "DVD":"150",
         "Date":"Wed Aug 01 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500"
      }
   },
   {
      "3":{
         "TV":"200",
         "Video":"50",
         "DVD":"100",
         "Date":"Thurs Aug 08 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500"
      }
   } continues.....
]
```

Below is the method that I'm working on...

```
var newObj = [];
for(var key in i){
 var thisMonth = i[key].Date.getMonth();
 if(thisMonth === 6){
    //Add each properties together and push to the new array
     console.log(thisMonth); //this results in two 6 (july).


 }else if(thisMonth === 7){
     //Add each properties together and push to the new array
     console.log(thisMonth); //this results in two 7 (August).

 }
}
return newObj;
```

What I would like this method to return is a new array with all the summed up data.

```
   [
     {
      "0":{
         "TV":"350",
         "Video":"110",
         "DVD":"300",
         "Date":"Jul 2014"
     },{
      "0":{
         "TV":"550",
         "Video":"70",
         "DVD":"250",
         "Date":"Aug 2014"

   ]
```

There may be a better approach to this, I appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific issue you're having a hard time with?

Comment: Here's something to get you started: http://jsbin.com/tucat/1/edit

Comment: Are the input and output data really arrays of *double wrapped* objects, or is this just a quirk of handraulic serialization? It would be more conventional to see simple arrays of objects.

Comment: Thanks elzi!
Nit - the issue I was having was adding the all the items by date and then returning an array of the added items.
Roamer - I'm using kendo ui to visualize this data and I need to pass the array to kendo chart.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pjcr4f4k/1/) for a solution that outputs an array, similar to what you want - but without the double-wrapping. To use it, you would need to pre-process your source data structure and post-process my output array.

Answer (score 0):

The below would never have worked

```
i[key].Date.getMonth();
```

As your `Date` property would have been a string and not a Date object so it would have stopped due to an undefined function error.

The below will accumulate the data, but instead of having an object with a single property named "0" containing the data, this will create an object with properties of `{month} {year}`, i.e. Aug 2014, Jul 2014, where the data is contained

```
var data = {};

//Loop over the array, use a regular for loop or
//forEach polyfill if supporting older browsers
i.forEach(function(item,index){
   //Since the object we want is a property
   //of the item object use the index as the key
   var obj = item[index];
   var d = new Date(obj.Date);

   //alternative way to get abbr. month then creating
   //an array of months and using the getMonth as an index to that array
   var m = d.toDateString().split(" ")[1];
   var y = d.getFullYear();

   //Check to see if there already is a month/year 
   //property creating one if not.
   var temp = data[m+" "+y] || {"TV":0,"Video":0,"DVD":0,"Date":""};

   temp.TV += +obj.TV;
   temp.Video += +obj.Video;
   temp.DVD += +obj.DVD;
   temp.Date =  m+" "+y;

   data[m+" "+y] = temp;   
});
console.log(data);
```

Will log the data object, and will have the the following format:

```
{
    "Jul 2014": {
        "TV": 350,
        "Video": 110,
        "DVD": 300,
        "Date": "Jul 2014"
    },
    "Aug 2014": {
        "TV": 550,
        "Video": 70,
        "DVD": 250,
        "Date": "Aug 2014"
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/09uttq8k/)

Comment: As an object, the output will be orderless, which may be an issue. In Javascript, only arrays have order.

Comment: Wow Patrick! thanks for putting this together for me. Could I work this with for in loop as well. It seems like the Date property is not working for me when I try it in forEach loop